# simple example on C++ client talk to node.js server using unix socket

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I just started coding couple months ago, I just want to get a simple example(such as hello world) on C++ client talk to nodejs server. I ve been searching online but it all comes out of C++ talk to c++ server. If someone can help me out, I would be much appreciate. THX

Comment: Talk how? What protocol? There's literally a [whole book on how to do this](http://www.unpbook.com) which is one place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have no example. Here is how to handle this in general.

Node.js works under web server. As any web server it communicates with client by GET/POST requests. So you have to take C++ http-library. Using it connect to your web server. Send to the server GET or POST request and take an answer from node.js.

GET/POST requests are very simple, use http-library to form it.

I believe node.js answers using xml/html. So you will have to parse the answer using appropriate library.